# Generating Raw Intel Processor Trace With Perf

Tags: debugging, intel, trace, processor, perf

I am tasked with generating a *raw* Intel Processor Trace. By raw, I mean the trace conforms to the file header:

```
struct pt_logfile_header {
    unsigned int magic;
    unsigned int version;
};
```

And is then followed by various process, thread, xpage and buffer structures:

```
/* logitem header */
struct pt_logitem_header {
    enum pt_logitem_kind kind;
    unsigned int size;
};
/* type process */
struct pt_logitem_process {
    struct pt_logitem_header header;
    unsigned long tgid;                 // process id
    unsigned long cmd_size;             // the size of command string followed to launch this process
};
/* type thread */
struct pt_logitem_thread {
    struct pt_logitem_header header;
    unsigned long tgid;                 // process id
    unsigned long pid;                  // thread id
};
/* type xpage */
struct pt_logitem_xpage {
    struct pt_logitem_header header;
    unsigned long tgid; // process id
    unsigned long base; // the base address where executable pages were mapped
    unsigned long size; // the total size of the executable pages
};
/* type buffer */
struct pt_logitem_buffer {
    struct pt_logitem_header header;
    unsigned long tgid; // process id
    unsigned long pid; // thread id
    unsigned long sequence; // a per-thread sequence number
    unsigned long size; // the total size of PT packets followed
};
```

Is `perf record` capable of creating this type of trace, or something very similar?

Comment: Where did you get pt_logfile_header and other headers? What is the exact name of this tracing mode (is it from Intel Software Developer docs)?

Answer (score 0):

Support of Intel Processor Trace (Intel PT, available in Intel 5th gen Core Broadwell, 6th gen Skylake, and in Goldmont Atoms: Intel Joule and Apollo Lake) was planned for adding to perf in 4.1 (kernel part) and 4.3 (user-space part) versions of the Linux kernel: https://lwn.net/Articles/648154/ "Adding Processor Trace support to Linux", Jul 2015:

> Processor Trace (PT) is a new tracing mechanism for Intel CPUs that traces branches executing on the CPU, which allows the reconstruction of the control flow of all executed code.  Intel CPUs have an older mechanism called BTS (Branch Trace Store) that also allowed branch tracing, but it was slow and not widely used. PT allows tracing with better performance and gathers additional information, such as timing. Intel Processor Trace is supported on Broadwell CPUs. More information can be found in the Processor Trace specification in the Intel Architecture Software Developer Manuals, volume 3, chapter 36.
>
> The 4.1 kernel has an implementation of Processor Trace in the kernel's perf_events subsystem that allows the use of PT through the perf interface. The user-tools support is not quite merged yet, but is expected for 4.2. The code was developed by Alex Shishkin and Adrian Hunter and was tested by Emmanuel Lucet. ...
>
> Here is an example that records the execution of a simple program
>
> ```
> % perf record -e intel_pt//u ls
> [ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
> [ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.190 MB perf.data ]
> ```

There should be some way of using `perf script` / `perf script -D`  or modifying perf source or other parsing of `perf.data` to extract raw PT logs.

Check also https://www.halobates.de/pt-tracing-summit15.pdf "Intel® Processor Trace on Linux" from Tracing Summit 2015 by Andi Kleen and Beeman Strong. It shows `perf script -D` output (last slide) containing raw PT dump in `PERF_RECORD_AUXTRACE` records.

There are also simple intel's tools to work with PT: https://github.com/andikleen/simple-pt

> simple-pt is a simple experimental reference implementation of Intel Processor Trace (PT) on Linux. PT can trace all branches executed by the CPU at the hardware level with moderate overhead. A PT decoder then uses sideband trace data to decode the branch traces.
>
> ```
> % sptcmd  -c tcall taskset -c 0 ./tcall
> cpu   0 offset 1027688,  1003 KB, writing to ptout.0
> ...
> Wrote sideband to ptout.sideband
> % sptdecode --sideband ptout.sideband --pt ptout.0 | less
> TIME      DELTA    INSNs   OPERATION
> ```
>
> simple-pt consists of a
>
> - kernel driver
> - `sptcmd` to collect data from the kernel driver
> - `sptdecode` to decode PT information
> - `fastdecode` to dump raw PT traces
> - It uses the `libipt` PT decoding library [https://github.com/01org/processor-trace]
>
> Simple PT does NOT support:
>
> - It does not support long term tracing of more data than fits in the buffer (no interrupt) (use `perf`)
> - It does not support any sampling (use `perf` or VTune)
> - It requires root rights to collect data (use `perf`)
> - It does not support interactive debugging (use `gdb` [7.10+] or hardware debuggers)

Comment: Also, post from Andi Kleen:  http://halobates.de/blog/p/406 "Intel Processor Trace resources" & older http://halobates.de/blog/p/344 "Announcing simple-pt — A simple Processor Trace implementation"

Comment: And also http://halobates.de/blog/p/410 "Cheat sheet for Intel Processor Trace with Linux perf and gdb"